# how to publish and parse custom payload for pubsub xmpp smack library

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, publish-subscribe, smack

this question is asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190546/how-to-send-receive-customize-item-payload-on-pubsub-node) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262301/parsing-eventelement-for-xmpp-using-smack-library) but i dont get answer from there.
I'm developing application in which i'm using pubsub and xmpp, for android i'm using smack library. i want to send custom payload to the node and on receiving custom payload how to parse and display it in to list? now i am able to send and receive message but it is just a small example from documentaion. here is my example,

```
String msg = "room pubsub test";

SimplePayload payload = new SimplePayload("message", "pubsub:test:message", "<message xmlns='pubsub:test:message'><body>" + msg + "</body></message>");

PayloadItem<SimplePayload> item = new PayloadItem<>(null, payload);

node.publish(item);
```

and when i receive item

```
node.addItemEventListener(new ItemEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void handlePublishedItems(ItemPublishEvent items) {
                  System.out.println("======================handlePublishedItems==============================");
                  System.out.println(items.getItems());
           }
}
```

and the output i'm getting is

```
[org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PayloadItem | 
Content [<item id='5E277A9C33A58'>
<message xmlns='pubsub:test:message'>
<body xmlns='pubsub:test:message'>room pubsub test</body><
/message>
</item>]]
```

i want to send custom payload like the time at which message is sent, who have sent this message etc. 
so, how can i send custom payload? and how to parse it and show it to user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send custom payload for time and sender using below code:

```
 SimplePayload payload = new SimplePayload("message", "pubsub:test:message", "<message xmlns='pubsub:test:message'><body>" + textMessage + "</body><from>"+Sender+"</from><time>"+time+"</time></message>");
```

For parsing you can use XmlPullParser and parse response using Tag name

Comment: can you give me example for XmlPullParser and parse response using Tag name?

Comment: @gaurang you can refer this link for parsing                                              [link]https://github.com/42cc/p2psafety/blob/master/p2psafety-android/p2psafety/src/ua/p2psafety/services/XmppService.java

Comment: can you tell me how to retrieve id from this 
<item id='5E28E3E1402B1'><message xmlns='pubsub:test:message'><body xmlns='pubsub:test:message'>pubsub test1</body><from xmlns='pubsub:test:message'>user1</from><time xmlns='pubsub:test:message'>1506582624630</time></message></item>

Comment: XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xml));                                                       xpp.getAttributeValue(null,"id");

Comment: it return null 
try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xml));
            
            String id = xpp.getAttributeValue(null,"id");
            Log.d("idddddddddddd",id);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }